# Is it necessary in Backbone to create Collections and Models every time?

Tags: backbone.js

For example I have a list of country regions. In this case I have:

- Model: *App.Models.Region*
- Collection: *App.Collections.RegionsList*
- Views: *App.Views.RegionView* and *App.Views.RegionsListView*

And if I want to create the view of regions list I need create My collection. To create collection I need to create a model... and all of that is boring. As the result I have something like that:

```
var regionModel = new App.Models.Region();
var regionsList = new App.Collections.RegionsList({ model: regionModel});
var regionsListView = new V.RegionsListView({el: $('#region'), collection: regionsList});
```

Does solution of this problem exist? What is best practices for the significant Views creation?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your region data static or does it change while your application is running?

Comment: data is static. List of regions from DB. But in general, I can remove something for example.. Question is - general approach. Or it is individual, there are no best practices...

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is pretty modular - you can use pieces as you deem appropriate.

However, a 'Collection' is a grouping of Models.  So it only makes sense to have both in regard to those.

As for the views, they exist to help you control how elements in your DOM are rendered.  So, you can use a View without the Models or Collections if that's all you want.

There's also a Router that is very helpful for single page apps - and you can use that separately if you wish.

Comment: oh, sorry for misunderstanding.. I need this models and collections. I am searching of best way to do the same. For example I could create an instance of `Model` inside of collection or so on...